# Independence and Random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal B, P)$ is the uniform probability space; that is, $([0,1],\mathcal B,\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the uniform probability distribution. Define
>   $$ X(\omega)=\omega.$$
>
> (a) Does there exist a bounded random variable that is both independent of $X$ and not constant almost surely?
>
> (b) Define $Y = X(1-X)$. Construct a random variable $Z$ such that $Z$ and $Y$ are independent.

Can someone help me with this exercise? I'm completely lost, I know the definitions and the meaning of Lebesgue measure, bounded random variable and independence, but I can't apply.

Comment: Hi again Marco -- can you give us more indication of what meaningful things you have tried to solve this question besides just "I know the definitions"? I ask only because you've posed several of these kinds of questions (i.e. screenshots of problem statements without much added to them) and I'm a bit worried that we're just doing your homework for you. Do you have an example of a random variable you constructed that didn't work, and some thoughts on why / how it didn't work, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

(a) No. $\sigma(X)=\mathcal{B}$. So for any r.v. $Y$ defined on that probability space $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\sigma(X)$.

(b) $Z(\omega)=1$.

Comment: how do you get this results?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about the Z(w), I mean, do you just choose a number such that obviously are independent or there is some reasoning behind?

Comment: $1$ is arbitrary.