# $X(\omega) = \omega $ is a random variable in the uniform probability space. Construct a random variable that is independent to $X(1-X)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

**Question**

(For reference, this appears on Resnick's "A probability path", p 110)

$(\Omega, \mathbb{B}, P)$ is the uniform probability space. That is:
$([0, 1], \mathbb{B}, \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the uniform probability distribution.
Let:

$$ X(\omega) = \omega$$

Now define $ Y = X(1 - X)$. Construct a random variable $Z$ such that $Z$ and $Y$ are independent.

**Has this been answered before?**

This question appears in [Independence and Random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520209/independence-and-random-variables), but

- That question is closed
- It has the answer $Z = 1$

While I agree that constant function would be independent, I'm wondering whether there's a non constant answer.

**My attempt**

By the Factorization Criterion, I just need to check that for all $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$ \lambda \left([ \;(Z(\omega) \leq z )\; \cap \; (\omega (1 - \omega) \leq y)\;] \right) = 
\lambda ( \; [(Z(\omega) \leq z]\; )  \cdot   \lambda( \; [\omega (1 - \omega) \leq y]\;)  $$

In case my notation is non-standard or unclear, with $[ (Z(\omega) \leq z ) \cap (\omega (1 - \omega) \leq y)]$ I mean the set of $\omega$ that fit those inequalities.

If I draw $\omega (1 - \omega) \leq y$, I see that:

$$[\omega (1 - \omega) \leq 1/4] = [0, 1] = \Omega$$

And that, as $y$ goes down to zero, it takes away from $\omega$s around $1/2$ and so the measure of that set is something like $[0, \omega_1] \cup [\omega_2, 1]$, where $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are usually the two solutions to the quadratic equation $w^2 - w + y = 0$.

My thought was then to try to find a functional form for $Z$ such that the info that $y$ gives (that is, the ruling out of some $\omega$s around $1/2$) wouldn't change the value of:

- The measure $\lambda ( \; [(Z(\omega) \leq z]\; )$  or
- the set $ [(Z(\omega) \leq z]$ for any arbitrary $z$

Either would be enough for independence.

However, I couldn't think of any functional form that would do this and not be constant.
Of course, the answer might be that it is not possible and only a constant $Z$ would do the job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $Y:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $Y(\omega) = \omega(1-\omega)$.

The following non-constant random variables $Z_1:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Z_2:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are both independent of $Y$:

\begin{align}
Z_1(\omega)&=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{ if $\omega \neq 0$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ if $\omega =0$} \end{array}\right.\\
Z_2(\omega) &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{ if $\omega \geq 1/2$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ if $\omega <1/2$} \end{array}\right.
\end{align}